# Limit number of records that are counted in sql

Tags: mysql

In my database I can easily see the last 50 people in my table with state=NY and postcode=12405 and I can look down the table to see if they have a dog.

```
    SELECT state, postcode, havedog
    FROM address
    WHERE (state=NY) AND (postcode=12405)
    ORDER BY surname DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Which returns

```
state   postcode    havedog
NY  12405   yes
NY  12405   yes
NY  12405   no
NY  12405   no
NY  12405   yes
```

I can also count how many people there are in my whole database that have a dog where state=NY and postcode=12405

```
    SELECT state, postcode COUNT(havedog) AS DOG
    FROM address
    WHERE (state=NY AND postcode=12405 ) AND (havedog=yes)
```

But I can't work out how to limit the count so it only counts the last 5 records where state=NY and postcode=12405 and havedog=yes, is it possible to apply a limit to the Count function?

eg given the table above, the result of my count should be 3.

Comment: Screen the 50 and then count out :-)

Comment: What SQL package are you using?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you give some example data and show what result you expect (you might want to change 50 to, say, 5 or 10 for the purpose of the example. This will simplify things and make the actual question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subselect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT state, postcode, havedog
    FROM address
    WHERE state = 'NY' AND postcode = 12405
    ORDER BY surname DESC
    LIMIT 5
) T1
WHERE havedog = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added more information to the question, your query is returning a count of 5 (if we are limiting to 5 now) which is fair enough as it is saying show the last 5 were havedog = 1 however I want to say over the last 5 records where state = ny and postcode = 12405 how many times does havedog = 1

Comment: Sorry for the inital confusion this is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  state,
  postcode
  COUNT(havedog) AS DogCounts
FROM
(
  SELECT state, postcode, havedog
  FROM address
  WHERE (state=NY) AND (postcode=12405)
  ORDER BY surname DESC
  LIMIT 50
) t
GROUP BY state, postcode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 50 state, postcode, COUNT(havedog) OVER () AS DOG
FROM address 
WHERE (state='NY' AND postcode=12405 ) AND (havedog='yes')
```